# Ошибка YII2 админка kit start

Tags: php, yii2

Ошибка в системном журнале

```
Access to debugger is denied due to IP address restriction. The requesting IP address
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит что доступ к дебаггеру запрещён для этого IP-адреса.

**Решение №1** Добавьте этот ip в список разрешенных (например, на dev)

В файле `common/config/web.php` сюда:

```
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => yii\debug\Module::class,
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', 'ЭТОТ_IP'],
];
```

**Решение №2** Если вам не нужен дебаггер (например, на prod)

В файле `.env` установите `YII_DEBUG = false`

**Решение №3** Отключите логирование дебаггера.

В файле `common/config/base.php` добавьте `'yii\debug\Module*'` сюда:

```
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            'db' => [
                'except' => ['yii\debug\Module*'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

И чтобы на prod такие ошибки не приходили на почту, добавьте `'yii\debug\Module*'` сюда:

```
$config['components']['log']['targets']['email'] = [
    'except' => ['yii\debug\Module*'],
];
```